# Woocommerce email invoice, shipping method style by instance_id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

In woocommerce I have one shipping zone and under it, there is seven shipping methods. Shipping method ids are 4 (local pick up), 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10. Last six are delivery. So in first, local pick up, I want to show only shipping method and in others show shipping ,ethod and shipping address

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}
$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
$address    = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
$shipping   = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();

$current_shipping_method_id = '';
$current_shipping_method = '';
$type = '';

foreach($order->get_items('shipping') as $item){
    $current_shipping_method_id = $item->get_instance_id().'<br>';
}

$shipping_packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();

foreach( array_keys( $shipping_packages ) as $key ) {
    if( $shipping_for_package = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_'.$key) ) {
        if( isset($shipping_for_package['rates']) ) {
            foreach ( $shipping_for_package['rates'] as $rate_key => $rate ) {
                $method_id = $rate->method_id;
                $instance_id = $rate->instance_id;

                if($instance_id == 4){ // Saņemt veikalā
                    $current_shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method();
                    $type = 4;
                }
                if($instance_id == 6){ // Piegāde darba dienās 9.00-17.00 (nesaskaņots, pēc servisa 
                vēlmēm)
                    $current_shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method().' ('.$order->get_shipping_address_1().' '.$order->get_shipping_address_2().')';
                    $type = 6;
                }
                if($instance_id == 7){ // Piegāde darba dienās 9.00-17.00 (Saskaņots pēc klienta vēlmēm)
                    $current_shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method().'('.$order->get_shipping_address_1().' '.$order->get_shipping_address_2().')';
                    $type = 7;
                }
                if($instance_id == 8){ // Bezmaksas piegāde
                    $current_shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method().' ('.$order->get_shipping_address_1().' '.$order->get_shipping_address_2().')';
                    $type = 8;
                }
                if($instance_id== 9){ // Omniva pakomāts
                    $current_shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method().' ('.$order->get_shipping_address_1().' '.$order->get_shipping_address_2().')';
                    $type = 9;
                }
                if($instance_id == 10){ // Omniva kurjers
                    $current_shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method().' ('.$order->get_shipping_address_1().' '.$order->get_shipping_address_2().')';
                    $type = 10;
                }
                if($instance_id == 11){ // DPD pakomāts
                    $current_shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method().' ('.$order->get_shipping_address_1().' '.$order->get_shipping_address_2().')';
                    $type = 11;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

?>
 <div class="p2">
    <table class="table2">
        <tr>
            <th>Pasūtītājs:</td>
            <td><?php echo $order->get_billing_first_name().' '.$order->get_billing_last_name(); ?> 
 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Kontakti:</th>
            <td>
                <a href="mailto:<?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( 
 $order->get_billing_email() ); ?></a>, 
                <?php echo wc_make_phone_clickable( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Preces saņemšana</th>
            <td><?php echo $order->get_shipping_method(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if($type == 6 || $type == 7 || $type == 8 || $type == 9 || $type == 10 || $type == 11){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <th>Saņemšanas vieta:</th>
            <td><?php echo $order->get_shipping_address_1().' '.$order->get_shipping_address_2(); ?> 
  </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <?php echo $type; ?>
    </div>
```

After new order, which is selected as local pick up, instance id 4, in email shows that current instance id is 4, but $type 11 why? I don't understand!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it different, but still don't understand why it's not working with type method

Now it's working:

```
<?php
        $instance_ids = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
        if(in_array($current_shipping_method_id, $instance_ids)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <th>Saņemšanas vieta:</th>
            <td><?php echo $order->get_shipping_address_1().' '.$order->get_shipping_address_2(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```